# Downloading file on background using .net 4.5.2 and angularjs

Tags: .net, angularjs, fire-and-forget

I need to download an excel file containing large numbers of data. Hence it takes almost over a minute to prepare the file, which keeps the http call open for a long time. 
To get rid of the issue, I tried the "fire and forget" approach as follows -
I'm generating the file on background using

```
> HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem
```

method. However, I'm getting the promise response on the client side (which is required for enabling the user to continue other tasks, without getting interrupted by the ongoing file download), but as the file generation is still on process on background, I'm not able to download the file.

Any solution/different approach of the functionality will be very much appreciated.

> Technologies used - .Net 4.5.2, Angular JS